# Continuous,Discontinuous ,Differential and non Differentiable function Graph properties

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives, continuity

I am quite familiar with how to prove differentiability and continuity of functions(by equations).This   doubt is  to get some meaningful information which I might have missed and it is related  to visual inspection of  graph plots.

**Continuous v/s discontinuous  function Graph**

With out solving  equations,  sometimes I can easily identify the non continuity of the graph because  there will be    breaks in the graph path. There should be non breaking path between any two points in a continuous function
[image]

**Doubt**

An example of graph which is continuous but not differentiable   is given below
[image].

Can we identify the non differentiable functions from graph plot as we did earlier in continuity? What I have found is given below

[image]

Is this visual inspection  method cover all non differentiable cases? If it misses some cases what are those cases?

NB :: I am not looking for a visual inspection method to substitute entirely   equation solving method. But I believe if I get such information , some times  it may save time

Comment: Definitely not. There are continous functions that are nowhere differentiable. You will be hard pressed to get a graph for them. Dirichlet created some and maybe easier to understand is the van der Waerden example.

Comment: I think Weierstrass also created a nowhere differentiable but continuous function. I think that functions is based on an infinite series if I am not mistaken